# Combinatorical question related to the number of groups of order $n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $n$ is a squarefree number, such that for every prime divisor $p|n$ , there exists at most one prime divisor $q|n$, such that $p|q-1$.

If this is the case, then the number of groups of order $n$ can be calculated
without knowing the primes (It is sufficient to know which pairs $(p,q)$ , $p<q$ prime divisors of $n$, satisfy $p|q-1$).

The prime divisors of $n$ are denoted $p_1,...,p_m$ with $p_1<p_2<...<p_m$

To calculate the number of groups of order $n$ in this special case, I transformed the problem to the following combinatorical problem.

Suppose, $s$ is a subset of the set of ordered pairs of the set $[1,...,m]$
(for example $s=\{(1,3),(2,3)\}$. This means $p_1|p_3-1$ and $p_2|p_3-1$)
Let $x$ be a subset of the set $S:=[1,...,m]$ and $y=S$ \ $x$. 
Let $p(x)=1$ , if for every $u\in x$, there exists $v\in y$ , such that $(u,v)\in s$. Otherwise set $p(x)=0$.

To get the number of groups of order $n$, we have to determine for how many subsets $x$ we have $p(x)=1$. $x$ can also be empty. In this case, we set $p(x)=1$.

> Is there an efficient method to calculate the number of subsets $x$ with $p(x)=1$ and therefore $gnu(n)$?

Comment: $ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 40, 48, 64]$ are the possible values for $7$ prime factors. Although a paper stated, that the so-called "good-gnus" very probably cover the whole set $\mathbb N$, I could not find a number with the desired property with $gnu(n)=7$ or $gnu(n)=11$. Can someone help me find such numbers ?